# How to get the cell in the method "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)"?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an app which can control the numberOfRowsInSection by touching the button in the first cell.

Like this Image.It is only one row in every section but 4 rows in a section which was pressed the button at low right of the cell.

So, I think ,If I can get the cell during using the method,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{      
    if(the Button is pressed){
        return 4
    }
    else {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Then I can get the value in the cell and judge if the button was pressed.

[image: This is my appDemo's Image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same demo long time ago, I add a bool property 'isShowDetail' to the header, and button action for switching the bool, then in numberOfRowInSection:

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ BOOL isShowDetail = [self.sectionStates[@(section)]boolValue];
if (isShowDetail) {
    NSDictionary *dict = self.dataList[section];
    NSArray *array = dict[@"friends"];
    return array.count;        
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}